Why is Blender is importing single objects as a collection of surface names instead of whole objects?
I unchecked both the Split By Object/" Group options for Blender import. The object was already set in my file conversion app to "Do not split object apart," however, when loaded into Blender it still appeared as two objects (a group of six surfaces and another group having two surfaces.  It's because of the way Lightwave processes objects having both plain meshes mixed with subd -- it separates them internally.  Two surfaces are subd meshes though the "Do not break object apart" option in PolyTrans was checked.  Can I combine them into one and name it "light cycle" instead of having one object named "Polygon_FACE" and another one named "Subpatch_PTCH."

The default Display mode in the Outliner is View Layer. (Dropdown just to the left of the Outliner Search field). Yours is currently set to Scenes which gives a different layout. Maybe that's what you're seeing?

There are many things to unpack here.
Importing OBJ files
As mentioned on Wavefront OBJ - Blender 4.2 Manual:

OBJ format is a popular plain text format, however, it has only basic geometry and material support.

Note
There is no support for armatures, lights, cameras, empty objects, parenting, or transformations. See Compatibility for more information.


And that is because it's the only things the format supports to begin with. See Wavefront .obj file - Wikiwand articles to learn more.
Unless you used a third party importer in your first attempt that adds extra functionalities such as importing objects into a collection or making up a form of new hierarchy, the default Blender OBJ importer would only give you a bunch of objects with no hierarchy, looking like this:

So for the "The first time I imported this .OBJ file" to happen as you described, it would have either been done using a third party addon, or with a different file format (and importer) that does support collections/groups.
See TeeTrinker's answer for more info on the default Importer.

That being said, if you did import some data as you describe from your first import, we wouldn't be able to see it from your screenshot. Even though it's not the topic of the question, I think this should be addressed too.
Textures and Objects

two of the eight surface textures this object contains do appear as "objects" which I can individually select [...] why only two of eight?

These are what we call textures in Blender:

By "surface textures" here, do you mean "mesh objects" instead?
To learn more:

Texture mapping - Wikiwand
Polygon mesh - Wikiwand

What we can see

The screenshot shows a single object called "light cycle".

The viewport let us know there are at least two objects, because the colors of the selection outline shows both dark and light orange. Light orange is for the active object (the last selected) and dark orange if for the rest of the selection (which could be one or more objects, we don't know).
The Outliner shows at least three "mesh objects":

There could be more of them as child of the ones we see in the outliner, we could see it by unfolding the hierarchy, or by a mesh object icon on the right side of the object name indicating it has other child mesh objects. Though here it's truncated because the size of the object name is too big for the outliner width:

If there was more than one child mesh object, the right-side icon would show the count number:

Scene Collections

The first time I imported this .OBJ file its name appeared in the Collection list.

Your outliner's Display Mode is set to Scenes, which lists all the scenes in your file, and with their respective content categorized per data-block types. Hence, you see categories of View Layers, Scene Collections, and Objects.
We do see the unfold icon on the left of the Scene Collections category, and a collection icon on the right, which means there is at least one collection in your scene. It could be the collection of your OBJ file, or another one.
We don't know until you unfold the category and look its content:

A matter of Outliner Display Modes

When I import it now, its name does not appear, instead, two of the eight surface textures this object contains do appear as "objects" which I can individually select.

It sounds like, instead of what we see in your screenshot, you expect to see something like this:

More precisely, a collection named after your OBJ, with the mesh objects inside.
By default, the outliner's Display Mode is set to View Layer, which lists the current view layer's element as per their own hierarchy without categorization. See the difference:

The View Layer Display Mode is probably what you are expecting to see right now, but the Scene Display Mode gives you a very different result.
But regardless of which Display Modes you use, you would be able to see the collections and objects of your scene, but you didn't do so as per your screenshot.

This depends a lot on the obj file and the import settings you've used.
In the .obj import there are options for splitting up an the .obj data:

Split By Object
Split By Group

If you want everything to be in one Blender object, uncheck both of those options.
The problem is that we don't know how the .obj was created and how the exporter has split up the mesh. Whoever did that export and splitting might have done something that does not make a lot of sense to you, which is a likely answer to your question "but why only two of eight [surface textures]?".
You can have "o"'s and "g"'s in an obj. Those are meant to be objects and groups with no universal definition that applies to all 3d programs, so potentially every application does something different. Every 3d modeling program can decide how it wants to represent its data in an export and usually the user can decide the specifics in the export settings. Most exporters allow you to split by material, smooth groups, vertex groups, all of which can be set by the author of a model in any way they want.

My theory worked!  I removed any subd meshes from the original Lightwave file and converted it to .ObJ which loaded into Blender as a single object.
